# Android Studio Java if statement with sqlitedatabase

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sqlite

I checked the code for red lines and red text, but there were none.
Through app inspection, I confirmed that the value test111 was correctly entered into AAAA1 in the database, and that the value test222 was correctly entered into BBBB1. And it worked fine up to this point.
After that, if AAAA1 is test111 by using an if statement in settext.java, I wrote code to set the TextView with ID Text_test in activity_main.xml to test111 using setText.
And if BBBB1 is test222 by using an if statement in settext.java, I wrote code to set the TextView with ID Text_test2 in activity_main.xml to test222 using setText.
But this doesn't work properly. How do I do it?
How do I fix setext.java?
There is no error message in logcat.

```
settext.java
import static com.example.test1.DBHelper.AAAA1;
import static com.example.test1.DBHelper.BBBB1;

public class settext extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView Text_test;
    TextView Text_test2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            if (DBHelper.AAAA1.equals("test111")) {
                Text_test.setText("test111");
            }
            if (DBHelper.BBBB1.equals("test222")) {
                Text_test.setText("test222");
            }
        }
}
```

```
input.java
Btn_aaaa.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        db.delete(AAAA, null, null);
        values.put(AAAA1, "test111");
        }
    db.insert(AAAA, null, values);
});
Btn_bbbb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        db.delete(BBBB, null, null);
        values.put(BBBB1, "test222");
        }
    db.insert(BBBB, null, values);
});
```

```
DBHelper.java
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DB_NAME = "String.db";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 3;

    public static final String TABLE_Value = "TABLE_Value";
    public static final String AAAA = "AAAA";
    public static final String AAAA1 = "AAAA1";
    public static final String AAAA = "BBBB";
    public static final String AAAA1 = "BBBB1";

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String createTableQueryAA = "CREATE TABLE " + AAAA + " (" +
                AAAA1 + " TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(createTableQueryAA);

        String createTableQueryBB = "CREATE TABLE " + BBBB + " (" +
                BBBB1 + " TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(createTableQueryBB);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + AAAA);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + BBBB);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Comment: By doing this check `DBHelper.AAAA1.equals("test111")`
you are checking to see if the value defined as `public static final String AAAA1 = "AAAA1";` is equal to `"test111"` which it is not.



I would suggest you take some time to look at how to work with Room database.
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room

Answer (score 0):

> There is no error message in logcat.

code wise there is nothing wrong, i.e. the App is doing exactly what you have told it to do.

However, the code `DBHelper.AAAA1.equals("test111")` and also  `(DBHelper.BBBB1.equals("test222"))` will always be false.

- `DBhelper.AAAA1` hold the value **`AAAA1`** it will never be "test111" (likewise for BBBB1).

  - AAA1 can never change as it is final, there is just the one occurrence for however many instances of DBHelper exist.

At a guess it would appear that you want to set the value displayed by the Text_test view to a value from the database.

So it would appear that you want to extract some data from one or both of the tables and test that to see if it is test111 and/or test222.

To extract data you typically use the SQLiteDatabase [**`Query`*](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#query(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))* method which returns a Cursor, which will contain 0-n rows.

- You may want to use/code `Cursor csr = db.query(DBHelper.AAAA,null,null,null,null,null,null);`

and then loop through the cursor or perhaps just look at the first row in the  cursor. so respectively either

```
while(csr.moveToNext()) {....}
```

or

```
if (csr.moveToFirst()) {...}
```

A cursor's row will have columns, those depending upon the columns that are extracted as per the 2nd parameter passed that is either **columns**, String[], where the each element is a column name (or expression) **OR** **`null`**. Null equates to the SQLite *, which stands for all columns (in your case all columns is just the 1 column, so null is simple).

So after a move????, if the move can be undertaken then true will be returned, if the move could not be undertaken (e.g. empty cursor, end of cursor) then false is returned. hence the while loop (for all rows) and the if for just the first row. Additionally the cursor will be positioned at the row.

You can then extract data from the column(s), you access a column according to it's offset. So the first column is at offset 0, the second at 1 ....

So to get the value from the first column you can use a `get????` method, where ???? is the type of the data. You want a String value so the `getString` method is apt. So you could have:-

```
String theString = csr.getString(0);
```

Or perhaps even :-

```
Text_test.setText(csr.getString(0));
```

**Tying it all Up**

Using your DBHelper class, just modified to eliminate the errors. Connsider the following activity, based upon combining your, what appears to be, two into a single activity with the two buttons and also the two TextViews.

The code for the entire Activity (MainActivity used for convenience) being:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView Text_test1111;
    TextView Text_test2222;
    Button Btn_AAAA;
    Button Btn_BBBB;
    DBHelper helper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Text_test1111 = this.findViewById(R.id.Text_test1111);
        Text_test2222 = this.findViewById(R.id.Text_test2222);
        Btn_AAAA = this.findViewById(R.id.Btn_aaaa);
        Btn_BBBB = this.findViewById(R.id.Btn_bbbb);

        helper = new DBHelper(this);
        db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        setTextViews();

        Btn_AAAA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                db.delete(DBHelper.AAAA,null,null);
                ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                contentValues.put(DBHelper.AAAA1,"test1111");
                db.insert(DBHelper.AAAA,null,contentValues);
                setTextViews();

            }
        });
        Btn_BBBB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                db.delete(DBHelper.BBBB,null,null);
                ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                contentValues.put(DBHelper.BBBB1,"test2222");
                db.insert(DBHelper.BBBB,null,contentValues);
                setTextViews();
            }
        });

    }

    private void setTextViews() {
        setATextView(DBHelper.AAAA,Text_test1111);
        setATextView(DBHelper.BBBB,Text_test2222);
    }
    private void setATextView(String table, TextView tv) {
        Cursor csr = db.query(table,null,null,null,null,null,null);
        if (csr.moveToFirst()) {tv.setText(csr.getString(0));} else tv.setText("NOTHING");
        csr.close(); /* ALWAYS CLose Cursors when done with the Cursor */
    }
}
```

- as can be seen code has been added to retrieve the data from the database (see setATextView for 1 piece of code that that can be used for  either table )

When first run the App shows:-

[image]

- i.e. no data aka Nothing has been found in the database, this because no button has been clicked.

clicking BBBB (noting that it calls setTextViews to set both TextViews) and:-

[image]

- as expected the value test2222 has been extracted from the database and used for the TextView.

clicking AAAA and:-

[image]